# SQL server create stored procedure syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Test @FilePath int
AS
    SELECT
       LastName, FirstName
    INTO 
       tmp_tblPerson
    FROM 
       OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (.txt, .csv)}','SELECT * FROM ' + @FilePath + "'")
GO
```

But I get a syntax error which I don't understand..?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_Test, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the reminder, however I just named the sp quick and dirty for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dynamic SQL when using using [`OPENROWSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190312.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). A workaround is to make the entire block use dynamically created SQL like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Test @FilePath int
AS
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        'SELECT LastName, FirstName 
        INTO tmp_tblPerson 
        FROM OPENROWSET(
            ''MSDASQL'',
            ''Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (.txt, .csv)}'', 
            ''SELECT * FROM '' + @FilePath)'

    EXEC(@sql)
```

As always with dynamic SQL, make sure you are not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Additionally, your query appears to be incorrect as I doubt you have a table with an integer as a name.

Comment: Great thanks. This will work. Oh and ummm the int datatype is my own typo..hehe...it is meant to be a VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

@filepath is int, you probably want something like

```
'SELECT * FROM ' + convert(varchar,@FilePath)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use